# Elements overlapping rows and columns

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Question:
Create a array x of shape (n_row.n_col), having first n natural numbers.
`N = 30, n_row= 6, n_col=5`

Print elements, overlapping first two rows and last three columns.

Expected output:

```
[[2 3 4]
 [7 8 9]]
```

My output:

```
[2 3 7 8]
```

My approach:

```
x = np.arange (n)

x= x.reshape(n_row,n_col)

a= np. intersect1d(x[0:2,],x[:,-3:-1])

print (a)
```

I couldn't think of anything else, please help

Answer (score 0):

The overlap of row and column slices of the **same array** is just the combined slice

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(30).reshape(6, 5)
x[:2,-3:]
```

Output

```
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

To compute the overlap by finding same elements is odd but possible

```
r, c = np.where(np.isin(x, np.intersect1d(x[:2], x[:,-3:])))

x[np.ix_(np.unique(r), np.unique(c))]
```

Output

```
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers are a bit convoluted...
Personally from the original question:

> Question: Create a array x of shape (n_row.n_col), having first n natural numbers. N = 30, n_row= 6, n_col=5
>
> Print elements, overlapping first two rows and last three columns.

I understand "sub-indexing":

```
N, n_rows, n_cols = 30, 6, 5
a = np.arange(N).reshape(n_rows, n_cols)
print(a[:2, -3:])
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3, 4],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```